# xorg: disable touch sensitivity on clickpad button area on Elantech clickpad

Tags: linux, xorg, touchpad

Clickpads have mouse buttons integrated. I always lay one finger on the (left) button (to be ready to press ;). The problem with this is, that I prevent myself moving the cursor with my finger if I lay one finger on the virtual left button.

How can I disable touch sensitivity on the bottom area of the clickpad that integrates tha button?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this link.  It gives help for Linux users to disable the lower area of the click pad, https://askubuntu.com/questions/221664/how-to-tune-touchpad-for-smaller-area.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Setting `synclient AreaBottomEdge=<N>` to non-`0` really makes a bottom area touch insensitive and leaves it clickable. But in my case, the upper area does not react on touch when laying a finger on the bottom area.